# Ember store adding attributes incorrectly

Tags: javascript, ember.js, local-storage, ember-cli

I'm using the latest version of ember-cli, ember-data, ember-localstorage-adapter, and ember.

I have a `Node` object which has a parent and children.  Since I had issues with creating multiple relationships with the same type of object, I decided to store the parentID in a string, and the childIDs in an array of strings.  However, when I create a new Node and try to add the new Node's to the parents array of IDs, the ID ends up being added to the correct parent, but also other parents.

```
level 1      0
            / \
level 2    1   2
           |   |
level 3    3   4
```

In a structure like this, 0, 1, and 2 all have correct child and parent IDs.  However, after adding 3 and 4, node 1 and node 2's childIDs are [3, 4], instead of [3], [4] respectively.

The Array attribute:

```
var ArrayTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
  serialize: function(value) {
    if (!value) {
      return [];
    }
    return value;
  },
  deserialize: function(value) {
    if (!value) {
      return [];
    }
    return value;
  }
});
```

The insertNode code:

```
insert: function(elem) {
  var i,
      _store = elem.node.store,
      newNodeJSON = elem.node.serialize();

  newNodeJSON.childIds = [];
  newNodeJSON.level = getNextLevel();

  _store.filter('node', function(node) {
    return node.get('level') === newnodeJSON.level-1;
  }).then(function(prevLevelNodes) {

    // if no other nodes yet
    if (prevLevelNodes.toArray().length === 0) {
      makeNewNode(_store, newNodeJSON, elem.node);
    }

    // else, generates however many nodes that are in the previous level
    else {
      prevLevelNodes.toArray().forEach(function(node, idx) {
        newNodeJSON.parentId = node.get('id');
        makeNewNode(_store, newNodeJSON, elem.node);
      });
    }
  });
}

var makeNewNode = function(_store, newNodeJSON, node) {

  console.log(newNodeJSON.parentId); // returns correct value

  var newNode = _store.createRecord('node', newNodeJSON);
  newNode.save();

  var newNodeId = newNode.get('id');

  if (newNode.get('parentId')) {
    _store.find('node', newNode.get('parentId')).then(function(n) {
      var cids = n.get('childIds');
      console.log(newNodeId); // returns expected value
      console.log(cids); // **DOESN'T RETURN AN EMPTY ARRAY**: returns array with [3,4]
      cids.push(newNodeId);
      console.log(n.get('childIds')); // returns array with [3,4]
      n.save();
    });
  }
```

To top this off, this error happens 90% of the time, but 10% of the time it performs as expected.  This seems to suggest that there's some sort of race condition, but I'm not sure where that would even be.  Some places that I feel like might be causing issues: the `ember-cli` compilation, passing the entire `_store` in when making a new node, `ember-data` being weird, `ember-localstorage-adapter` being funky... no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who may have this problem in the future: the problem lies in two things.

- In ArrayTransform, typically I am returning the value sans modification.
- In my `insert` code, I'm passing the *same JSON* that I defined at the top of the function to `makeNewNode`.

This JSON contains a reference to a single `childIds` array; therefore, each new node that gets created *uses this same reference* for its childIds.  Although this doesn't quite explain why the `cids` array wasn't empty before the `push` executed (perhaps this is some sort of compiler oddity or console printing lag), it explains why these both Level 3 children were in both Level 2 parents' `childIds` array.

**tl;dr: pass by value vs pass by reference error**